# How shiftOut function works internally? (explanation on source code)

Tags: c++, arduino-ide, core-libraries

I were examining `shiftOut()` function code in `wiring_shift.c` and I didn't quite understand what is going in digitalWrite function. I see `!!(val & (1 << i))` is taking the bit value from `val` but how exactly it works?

The whole function is below.

```
void shiftOut(uint8_t dataPin, uint8_t clockPin, uint8_t bitOrder, uint8_t val)
{
    uint8_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)  {
        if (bitOrder == LSBFIRST)
            digitalWrite(dataPin, !!(val & (1 << i)));
        else    
            digitalWrite(dataPin, !!(val & (1 << (7 - i))));

        digitalWrite(clockPin, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(clockPin, LOW);        
    }
}
```

Comment: `!!(val & (1 << i))` is the most complex part of this code. If you _do_ understand this, then what is the part you do _not_ understand?

Comment: @edgar-bonet Actually this was the question. I can see it somehow calculates the bit value, but I didn't understand how it do this.

Comment: You do understand the behaviour of the shiftOut function?
I mean, you do understand that it'll `shift out` a value (in binary form). And will give a clock pulse along with it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'll assume `bitOrder == LSBFIRST`.

- `i` is the bit number, i.e. the “index” of the next bit to write
- `1` is `00000001` in binary
- `<<` is the shift left operator. It returns its first argument shifted left by as many positions as indicated by the second argument
- `1<<i` is binary `00000001` shifted left by `i` positions, i.e. something like `0...010...0`, where the single 1 is in the i-th position counting from the right (rightmost being position 0)
- `&` is the “bitwise and operator”, where `any_bit & 0` is zero and `any_bit & 1` is `any_bit`
- `val & (1 << i)` is `0...0(i-th bit of val)0...0` in binary, where the i-th bit of val is in the i-th position of the result
- `!!` is a double negation: it converts zero to zero and any non-zero value to one
- `!!(val & (1 << i))` is either 0 or 1, and is exactly the i-th bit of val

Comment: let me summarize what I understand. Let assume `val = '10010111'`;

    `for i=2`
      `!!(val & (1 << i))` = `!!('10010111' & '00000100')` = `!!('00000100')` = `1`

If i is = 3
  `!!(val & (1 << i))` = `!!('10010111' & '00001000')` = `!!('00000000')` = `0`

Comment: This is correct!

Comment: And this means if I give 16bit or longer data to shiftOut, it will send least significant 8 bits and ignore the rest.

Comment: `shiftOut()` takes `uint8_t` data. If you call it with a 16-bit argument, the compiler will implicitly remove the 8 most significant bits _before_ the actual call to `shiftOut()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations above. This has been invaluable helping with understanding and re-using the code elsewhere. I see that double negation converts zero to zero and any non-zero value to one; I can't see what else it could be. Without double negation, wouldn't the output be the same anyway? What is it I am missing?

Comment: @SteveMcDonald: Yes, the output would be the same without the double negation, _because_ `digitalWrite()` interprets _any_ non-zero value (not just 1) as meaning `HIGH`. Apparently, the author of `shiftOut()` did not want to rely on this behavior, and instead wanted to always call `digitalWrite()` with either 0 (i.e. `LOW`) or 1 (`HIGH`).